# ios,tableView.setEditing set default select rows

Tags: ios

TableView.setEditing how to set the default selection row,

```
 tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
              DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.6) {
                CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
                CATransaction.commit()
                tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition.none)
            }
```

Comment: Please, use this link, to explain what you need help with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method :

```
func setEditing(nil, true).
```

**`Nil` means `default` value of `setEditing`.**